# How do I use pandas groupby function to apply a formula based on the groupby value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My question may be a little confusing, so let me explain. I have a dataframe of information that I would like to group by the unique order id that will produce the following columns:

sum qty = the total amount that was executed per order id.
csv = this is the sum of the csv column per order id divided by the sum of the executed amount of the order id.

The first column is easy to create with groupby, it's the second column that I am having issues with. Here is sample data that I am working with:

```
    qty     sym     price   ordrefno    ord_bidprice    ord_askprice    csv
0   -25000  TEST    0.044   984842      0.0435          0.044          12.5
1   100     TEST    0.0443  984702      0.0435          0.044          0.03
2   -10000  TEST    0.0405  983375      0.039           0.0405         15
3   -100    TEST    0.0443  984842      0.0435          0.044          0.03
```

This is my code:

```
cs1 = lambda x: np.sum(test.csv / test.qty)
f2 = {'qty' : ['sum'], 'csv' : {'es' : cs1}}

agg_td = trades.groupby('ordrefno').agg(f2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a named funtion and using `apply` works:

```
def func(group):
    sum_ = group.qty.sum()
    es = (group.csv / group.qty).sum()
    return pd.Series([sum_, es], index=['qty', 'es'])

trades.groupby('ordrefno').apply(func)
```

Result:

```
            qty     es
ordrefno               
983375   -10000 -0.0015
984702      100  0.0003
984842   -25100 -0.0008
```

Comment: Ty for the quick responses. I tried this approach, but I am getting object information.


ordrefno        qty        es

2416709007 6858     <function csv at 0x125FEBB0> 

2416760168 25000   <function csv at 0x125FEBB0> 

2416818632 37480   <function csv at 0x125FEBB0> 

2416956429 95100   <function csv at 0x125FEBB0>

Comment: Sorry. Editing problem. I corrected the function. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the ratio of the sums rather than the sum of the ratios (the way the question is worded suggest this but the function in you code would give the sum of the ratios if applied to the df), I think the cleanest way to do this is in two steps. First just get the sum of the two columns and then divide:

```
agg_td = trades.groupby('ordrefno')[['qty', 'csv']].sum()
agg_td.eval('es = csv/qty')
```

You could also create a special function and pass it to the groupby `apply` method:

```
es = trades.groupby('ordrefno').apply(lambda df: df.csv.sum() / df.qty.sum())
```

But this will only get you the `'es'` column. The problem with using `agg` is that the dict of functions are column-specific where here you need to combine two columns.