# Python - How do I use calculated functions with pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and would like to aggregate the date by 3 columns and add some calculated columns on the end.

Dataframe columns:

```
cols = ["region_2",
        "trade_flag",
        "trade_target",
        "broker",
        "trade_shares",
        "total_value",
        "commission_in_gbp",
        "IS/Order Start PTA - Realized Cost/Sh",
        "IS/Order Start PTA - Realized Net Cost/Sh",
        "IS/Order Start PTA - Base Bench Price",
        "IS/Order Start PTA - P/L"]
```

Example input:

```
    region_2    trade_flag  trade_target    broker  trade_shares    total_value commission_in_gbp   IS/Order Start PTA - Realized Cost/Sh   IS/Order Start PTA - Realized Net Cost/Sh   IS/Order Start PTA - Base Bench Price   IS/Order Start PTA - P/L    count
0   EMEA    flag1   target1 broker1 3900    39532   0.00406 -0.067  -0.067  10.2037 -261.91 1
1   APAC    flag2   target2 broker2 1700    17232   0.00406 -0.067  -0.067  10.2037 -114.17 1
2   AMER    flag1   target1 broker3 1400    14191   0.00406 -0.067  -0.067  10.2037 -94.02  1
3   EMEA    flag2   target2 broker2 2000    20273   0.00406 -0.067  -0.067  10.2037 -134.31 1
```

Desired output:

```
region_2 | trade_flag | broker | count | total_value | perf | net perf
```

The perf columns on the end are weighted average calculations.

The code I have following another example which doesn't work (KeyError)

```
df['count'] = 1
df['perf'] = ""
df['net perf'] = ""

wm = lambda x: x['IS/Order Start PTA - Realized Cost/Sh'] * x['trade_shares'] * 10000 / x['IS/Order Start PTA - Base Bench Price'] * x['trade_shares']
wm2 = lambda x: x['IS/Order Start PTA - Realized Net Cost/Sh'] * x['trade_shares'] * 10000 / x['IS/Order Start PTA - Base Bench Price'] * x['trade_shares']

f = {'trade_shares': ['sum'],
     'total_value': ['sum'],
     'count': ['sum'],
     'perf': {'weighted mean' : wm},
     'net perf': {'weighted mean' : wm2}}

df = df.groupby(['region_2', 'trade_flag', 'broker']).agg(f)

df = df[['region_2', 'trade_flag', 'broker', 'count', 'total_value', 'actual', 'net']]
```

Comment: Can you add some sample input data, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: I have added all the columns in the dataframe. I am not sure how to past raw data here.

Comment: You can check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: Done. Although it didn't paste well

Answer (score 0):

you can use pivot_table instead of groupby

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(
        df,
        index=[
            'region_2',
            'trade_flag',
            'broker',
        ],
        values=[
            'trade_shares',
            'total_value',
            'count',
            'perf',
            'net perf'
        ],
        aggfunc={
            'trade_shares': np.sum,
            'total_value': np.sum,
            'count': np.sum,
            'perf': wm,
            'net perf': wm2
        }
    )
```

Though it would help to see the actual error message and sample input to see if that's the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am getting a KeyError on one of the columns used in the wm calculations (KeyError: 'IS/Order Start PTA - Realized Cost/Sh').

Answer (score 0):

You need [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), because [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) working with each column separately, so `KeyError`:

```
def f(x):
    a =  x['trade_shares'].sum()
    b =  x['total_value'].sum()
    c =  len(x)
    #x['perf'] = x['IS/Order Start PTA - Realized Cost/Sh'] * x['trade_shares'] * 10000 / x['IS/Order Start PTA - Base Bench Price'] * x['trade_shares']
    #x['net perf'] = x['IS/Order Start PTA - Realized Net Cost/Sh'] * x['trade_shares'] * 10000 / x['IS/Order Start PTA - Base Bench Price'] * x['trade_shares']
    return pd.Series([a,b,c], index=['trade_shares','total_value','count'])

df = df.groupby(['region_2', 'trade_flag', 'broker']).apply(f).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The above code seems to add the columns to end of the existing dataframe, whereas I want to aggregate the results by region_2, trade_flag and broker. For example, the number of rows in the dataframe hasn't changed after implementing the above.

Comment: Yes, there are 3 new columns

Comment: And theses columns you define above your solution - `df['count'] = 1
df['perf'] = ""
df['net perf'] = ""`

Comment: @User63164 - in my solution are not necessary, but if want, you can define them same way. Then change `x['count'] =  len(x)` to `x['count'] =  x['count'].sum()`

Comment: Yes. But the output is not aggregated and it contains all the columns, whereas I only want the results aggregated by those columns in the desired output in the OP. Similar to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485787/how-do-i-use-pandas-groupby-function-to-apply-a-formula-based-on-the-groupby-val

Comment: @User63164 - Yes, you are right, problem is with `wm = lambda x: x['IS/Order Start PTA - Realized Cost/Sh'] * x['trade_shares'] * 10000 / x['IS/Order Start PTA - Base Bench Price'] * x['trade_shares']
wm2 = lambda x: x['IS/Order Start PTA - Realized Net Cost/Sh'] * x['trade_shares'] * 10000 / x['IS/Order Start PTA - Base Bench Price'] * x['trade_shares']` - data are not aggregtae in this lambda functions.

Comment: It seems that it is trying to apply the groupby on all the columns in the dataframe, whereas I am only interested in a subset

Comment: @User63164 - problem is with formulas, there is no mean or sum - so not aggregate

Comment: I tried without those two formulas and the result is still the same e.g just grouping by trade_shares, total_value and the count

Comment: @User63164 - You are right, sorry, eited answer. Removed weights for correct aggregation